# Enter in parameter value SQL in MS Access (latest version)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am running into this issue where I keep getting this dialog box appearing asking me to enter in parameter values when it shouldn't be. Here is the code:

```
SELECT ProductionCost
FROM tblFilm
WHERE ProductionCost >"220";
```

It keeps popping up with the dialog box. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: What does the pop-up box ask for? Likely it is due to a field name the db engine cannot recognize. Check if *ProductionCost* really exists in the table *tblFilm*.

Comment: It asks for to enter in a parameter value for ProductionCost. Yes ProductionCost exists in the table. Its actually labelled as ProductionCost($m) however when I put that in then it says there is an syntax error as it doesn't like the dollar sign.

Comment: In the SQL, wrap the name in square brackets `[ProductionCost($m)]` or backticks to escape spaces or special characters like `$`. Even better, avoid such names and use only alphanumerics.

Comment: It worked! Sweet! Awesome! Thank you Parfait! Learned something new